# Wordpress. Нужно создать 2 варианта шаблона под один тип поста

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Установлен Woocommerce, в общем задача, нужно чтобы при переходе на страницу продукта с сайта была стандартная страница, а при переходе с ссылки высланной на почту вся навигация, header, footer были скрыты, это можно было бы сделать GET параметром, но правильнее разными ссылками, как такое можно сделать, незнаю куда копать

Comment: А у вас ссылка на продукт с почты и сайта как-то отличаются?

Comment: не, но нужно например чтобы урлы 
/product/test и /em/product/test например вели на один продукт но у второй ссылки отсутствовали header и footer

Answer (score 0):

Открываете шаблон themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce/single-product.php

находите фрагмент

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

заменяете

```
<?php $param = $_GET['param'] ?? ''; ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php the_post(); ?>
            
            <?php if ($param == 'test') { ?>
      
                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product2' ); ?>
                    
            <?php } else { ?>
            
                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
            
            <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce/content-single-product2.php - вид с параметров GET param == test

themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce/content-single-product.php - оригинальный вид

Навигацию убираем в header.php, footer.php

проверками

```
<?php $param = $_GET['param'] ?? ''; ?>

<?php if (!(is_singular('product') && $param == 'test')): ?>

   <!-- показываем нужное -->
    
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Неплохо бы, если тема не своя, а приобретённая или бесплатная, но чужая, делать всё это в дочерней теме, а иначе с обновлением, всё улетит.